# Variable number of arguments in VB

Tags: vb6

How to create a function with variable number of arguments in visual basic?
ex.

```
x =  Sum(1,2,3)
y =  Sum(1,2)

Function Sum('how to declare argument here')
'Is there any special argument manipulation inside function before it is usable?
End Function
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at [Passing a Variable Number of Arguments](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=32096&seqNum=4)

```
Function Sum(ParamArray Vals() As Variant)
    Dim intLoopIndex As Integer
    For intLoopIndex = 0 To  UBound(Vals)

    Next intLoopIndex

End Function
```

Comment: Will this also work on VBA? I tried it on VBA but it is not working. It can't recognize ParamArray

Comment: The code above has the right idea, but won't compile as-is. 1) A `ParamArray` can't be declared `ByVal` and 2) it can only be declared as a `Variant` array. Therefore, the function declaration should be `Function Sum(ParamArray Vals() As Variant)`

Comment: @ Mike Spross: It works based on the rules you stated. Thanks.
@ astander: thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Mike Spross, @Katz, @astander  I have taken the liberty of editing astander's answer to correct the syntax. Mike was quite right about the changes needed. (Also +1 to Arvo who has also suggested optional arguments)

Answer (score 12):

Use optional arguments, like:

```
Function Sum(Optional X1 As Integer=0, Optional X2 As Integer=0)
```

or universally variable arguments syntax

```
Function Sum(ParamArray XArr() As Variant)
```

(I may have messed with some syntax elements - feel free to correct.)

Answer (score 4):

The answers here are great. In my application I required an arbitrarily long list of optional arguments after a required initial argument.

You can do this by simply adding the required arguments before the ParamArray entry.

For example:

```
Function Arithmetic(FuncType As String, ParamArray Terms() As Variant)
```