# How to create function to take indefinite number of arguments but by pairs?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm thinking of creating a VBA function similar to **IFS** formula wherein you could pass indefinite number of arguments but the second argument is always required.

`=IFS(logical_test1, value_if_true1, [logical_test2, value_if_true2], ...)`

The requirement is to compare certain values and if all are the same then output True, otherwise False.

Let's say we have this table.

```
Item ID | Price | Description
1001    | 10.00 | Item A
1002    | 10.00 | Item A
1003    | 25.00 | Item A
1004    | 10.00 | Item B
```

And if I need to do something on certain items, I would simply call the function like this:

`Function(criteria1, value1, criteria2, value2, ...)`

```
' Mark items with Price = 10.00 and Description = Item A
Dim IsAdd As Boolean: IsAdd = FnCheckData(strCriteria2, "10.00", strCriteria3, "Item A")

' Mark items with Item ID = 1002
Dim IsAdd As Boolean: IsAdd = FnCheckData(strCriteria1, "1002")

' Mark items with Item ID = 1003, Price = 25.00 and Description = Item A
Dim IsAdd As Boolean: IsAdd = FnCheckData(strCriteria1, "1003", strCriteria2, "25.00", strCriteria3, "Item A")

' This would error out since the second argument is not supplied
Dim IsAdd As Boolean: IsAdd = FnCheckData(strCriteria1)
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You possibly need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630171/variable-number-of-arguments-in-vb)

Comment: I covered this in a TEXTJOINIFS UDF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716550/textjoin-for-xl2010-xl2013-with-criteria/50719050?s=1|85.1472#50719050).

Comment: Thanks guys! had ideas from both posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function could look like that

```
Function NeedEvenNumber(ParamArray vStrings()) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo EH

    If IsMissing(vStrings) Then
        Debug.Print "Nothing passed"
    End If

    If (UBound(vStrings) Mod 2) - 1 = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Correct number of params passed"
    End If

    Exit Function

EH:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong", vbOKOnly, "Error"


End Function
```

Comment: Turn the return into a `Variant` and you can return `CVErr(xlErrNum)` (**#NUM!**) on errors.  [CVErr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function)